# MySQL Query Command Grab Value From Cell

Tags: mysql

Okay, I am experienced in PHP, HTML, CSS, and JS but am getting adapted to MySQL. Here I have a table with a structure like so:

```
username password data
______________________
bob      password 3983
tim      password 9872
jim      password 3892
```

And so forth. What is the simplest way to get Tim's data for instance? The SELECT command according to the MySQL documentation is for selecting a row, but I need to grab the value from an individual table cell in a row. Thank you!

Note: I did Google for this answer but all I get is a ton of 10 page documentations

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the data columns you're interested in after the `SELECT` keyword:

```
SELECT data FROM table WHERE username = 'tim';
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I actually had the syntax almost correct except I forgot the FROM table portion.